# Why does LinearRegression with polynomial features with degree = 1 gives different results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a dataset for regression: (X_train_scaled, y_train) and (X_val_scaled, y_val) for training and validation respectively. The inputs were scaled using StandardScaler.

I create a linear regression model using sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression like follows:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

linear_reg = LinearRegression()

linear_reg.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
y_pred_train = linear_reg.predict(X_train_scaled)
y_pred_val = linear_reg.predict(X_val_scaled)

r2_train = r2_score(y_train, y_pred_train)
r2_val = r2_score(y_val, y_pred_val)

print('r2_train', r2_train)
print('r2_val', r2_val)
```

After that I do the same but use polynomial features with degree = 1 (which are just the same as the original features but with an additional feature of ones, i.e. x^0, which I ignore).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

pf = PolynomialFeatures(1)
X_train_poly = pf.fit_transform(X_train_scaled)[:, 1:] # ignore first col
X_val_poly = pf.transform(X_val_scaled)[:, 1:] # ignore first col

linear_reg = LinearRegression()

linear_reg.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
y_pred_train = linear_reg.predict(X_train_poly)
y_pred_val = linear_reg.predict(X_val_poly)

r2_train = r2_score(y_train, y_pred_train)
r2_val = r2_score(y_val, y_pred_val)

print('r2_train', r2_train)
print('r2_val', r2_val)
```

However, I get different results. The first code gives me the following outputs:

```
r2_train 0.7409525513417043
r2_val 0.7239859358973735
```

whereas the second code gives this output:

```
r2_train 0.7410093370149977
r2_val 0.7241725658840452
```

Why are the outputs different although the dataset and model are the same?

To prove the datasets are the same, I tried the following code:

```
print(X_train_scaled.shape, X_train_poly.shape)
print(X_val_scaled.shape, X_val_poly.shape)
print((X_train_poly != X_train_scaled).sum())
print((X_val_poly != X_val_scaled).sum())
```

which has the output:

```
(802, 9) (802, 9)
(268, 9) (268, 9)
0
0
```

which indicates that the two datasets are identical.

Also, I use LinearRegession in the two cases which uses OLS algorithm and has no random operations at all. So, it's supposed to do the same calculations on the same data. However, I get different results.

Does anyone have an idea about the reason?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The R2 scores look really close (close enough that the results could be due to variance), are they trained on the exact same data or is there a `train_test_split` somewhere that could be dividing things differently?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes, Thank you. The two models are identical and are trained on identical datasets. I expect the results to be identical as well. However, the code outputs are slightly different. My goal is to find out the reason for this difference.

Comment: I can't recreate this, using the `sklearn.datasets.load_boston` dataset.

Comment: @BenReiniger Yeah I tried load_boston and it works as expected. Sounds strange. Maybe the problem is specific to my dataset? I use [US-Health-Insurance-Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/teertha/ushealthinsurancedataset) from Kaggle. I encoded both sex and smoker as binary features using 0 and 1, and encoded region feature using one-hot encoding. After that I split the dataset to (60% training, 20% validation, 20% test) and scaled the data using StandardScaler. Then I write the code I included in this question.

Comment: If you can whittle the data down to something you can post here while keeping the behavior, that'd be ideal. I can try it with the kaggle data later if not. Are the `coef_` and `intercept_` of the two models the same?

Comment: @BenReiniger, the `coef_` is different, but `intercept_` is the same. I noticed that `coef_` is very different for one-hot or binary features whereas it's slightly different for numeric features. However, when I used MinMaxScaler instead of StandardScaler the `coef_` of the two models become the same and the results become identical as well. I think there's something wrong about using StandardScaler for binary or one-hot features, although I can't determine the reason.

Comment: I still get the same results using the kaggle dataset, encoding the three columns as you mentioned.  Please provide your preprocessing code.  Perhaps there's some datatype issue, or maybe there's a silly overlooked mistake?...

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn LinearRegression uses ordinary least squares optimization to fit train data into a linear model while it is not clear what Sklearn PolynomialFeatures use. But based on its transform() function:

> Prefer CSR over CSC for sparse input (for speed), but CSC is required
> if the degree is 4 or higher. If the degree is less than 4 and the
> input format is CSC, it will be converted to CSR, have its polynomial
> features generated, then converted back to CSC.
> (see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)

Assuming PolynomialFeatures uses ordinary least squares optimization, you would still have same results but with slight difference (just like yours) because Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) method would compromise float values (in other words, truncation/approximation error).

Comment: But if PolynomialFeatures modifies my data, how does `(X_train_poly != X_train_scaled).sum()` and `(X_val_poly != X_val_scaled).sum()` both return 0 (which indicates both datasets are identical)? I think PolynomialFeatures doesn't modify the data at all for degree=1.

Comment: Hello Abdulwahab. I got your point. It will return to zero for sure. After you get the models, which in your case are identical for both linear and polynomial (n=1) as shown in your last results, the evaluation would differ, meaning, you have different r2 scores, not because there are two different r2 score formulas, but because of the computing difference during the evaluation, where in, the former uses ordinary least squares while the other uses other method (CSC) which generally intended for n>2 polynomials. However the difference, they both results to similar and significant results.